# Theme supports only one menu. I need to add more - but how?

Tags: menus

My theme is Nisarg. I will give all the coding below.
I have looked everywhere in order to add a navigation menu I'm trying to construct a website that gives lots of information and hence requires many menus.
I have never coded before nor recognise any of the language.
I see extracts from people to add code when I do it - it just crashes my site and says there are errors on various lines.
I can't get any info for a beginner for anywhere- so anyone? please? Just point me to a decent dummy guide (it took me hours to find functions.php and that you can edit)

Code is here:

```
<?php
/**
 * Nisarg functions and definitions
 *
 * @package Nisarg
 */


if ( ! function_exists( 'nisarg_setup' ) ) :
/**
 * Sets up theme defaults and registers support for various WordPress features.
 *
 * Note that this function is hooked into the after_setup_theme hook, which
 * runs before the init hook. The init hook is too late for some features, such
 * as indicating support for post thumbnails.
 */

/**
 * Nisarg only works in WordPress 4.1 or later.
 */
if ( version_compare( $GLOBALS['wp_version'], '4.2', '<' ) ) {
    require get_template_directory() . '/inc/back-compat.php';
}

function nisarg_setup() {
    /*
     * Make theme available for translation.
     * Translations can be filed in the /languages/ directory.
     * If you're building a theme based on Nisarg, use a find and replace
     * to change 'nisarg' to the name of your theme in all the template files
     */
    load_theme_textdomain( 'nisarg', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );

    // Add default posts and comments RSS feed links to head.
    add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );

    /*
     * Let WordPress manage the document title.
     * By adding theme support, we declare that this theme does not use a
     * hard-coded <title> tag in the document head, and expect WordPress to
     * provide it for us.
     */
    add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );

    /*
     * Enable support for Post Thumbnails on posts and pages.
     *
     * @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support#Post_Thumbnails
     */
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    set_post_thumbnail_size( 604, 270);
    add_image_size( 'nisarg-full-width', 1038, 576, true );


    function register_nisarg_menus() {
        // This theme uses wp_nav_menu() in one location.
        register_nav_menus( array(
            'primary' => esc_html__( 'Top Primary Menu', 'nisarg' ),
        ) );
    }


    add_action( 'init', 'register_nisarg_menus' );


    /*
     * Switch default core markup for search form, comment form, and comments
     * to output valid HTML5.
     */
    add_theme_support( 'html5', array(
        'search-form',
        'comment-form',
        'comment-list',
        'gallery',
        'caption',
    ) );


    /*
     * Enable support for Post Formats.
     * See http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats
     */
    add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array(
        'aside',
        'image',
        'video',
        'quote',
        'link',
        'gallery'
    ) );


    // Set up the WordPress core custom background feature.
    add_theme_support( 'custom-background', apply_filters( 'nisarg_custom_background_args', array(
        'default-color' => 'f5f5f5',
        'default-image' => '',
    ) ) );
}
endif; // nisarg_setup
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'nisarg_setup' );

/**
 * Sets the content width in pixels, based on the theme's design and stylesheet.
 *
 * Priority 0 to make it available to lower priority callbacks.
 *
 * @global int $content_width
 *
 */
function nisarg_content_width() {
    $GLOBALS['content_width'] = apply_filters( 'nisarg_content_width', 640 );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'nisarg_content_width', 0 );


/**
 * Register widget area.
 *
 * @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar
 */
function nisarg_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => esc_html__( 'Sidebar', 'nisarg' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
        'description'   => '',
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
        'before_title'  => '<h4 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h4>',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'nisarg_widgets_init' );

/**
 * Enqueue scripts and styles.
 */
function nisarg_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/bootstrap.css' );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'nisarg-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome', get_template_directory_uri().'/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css' );   

    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.js',array('jquery'),'',true);  

    wp_enqueue_script( 'nisarg-skip-link-focus-fix', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js', array('jquery'), '20130115', true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'nisarg-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/nisarg.js',array('jquery'),'',true);    

    wp_enqueue_script( 'html5shiv', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/html5shiv.js', array(),'3.7.3',false );
    wp_script_add_data( 'html5shiv', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9' );

    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'nisarg_scripts' );


/**
 * Implement the Custom Header feature.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/custom-header.php';

/**
 * Custom template tags for this theme.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/template-tags.php';

/**
 * Custom functions that act independently of the theme templates.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/extras.php';

/**
 * Customizer additions.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/customizer.php';

/**
 * Load Jetpack compatibility file.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/jetpack.php';
/**
 * Load custom nav walker
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/navwalker.php';


function nisarg_google_fonts() {
    $query_args = array(

        'family' => 'Lato:400,300italic,700|Source+Sans+Pro:400,400italic'
    );
    wp_register_style( 'nisarggooglefonts', add_query_arg( $query_args, "//fonts.googleapis.com/css" ), array(), null );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'nisarggooglefonts');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'nisarg_google_fonts');


function nisarg_new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return '...<p class="read-more"><a class="btn btn-default" href="'. esc_url(get_permalink( get_the_ID() )) . '">' . __(' Read More', 'nisarg') . '<span class="screen-reader-text"> '. __(' Read More', 'nisarg').'</span></a></p>';
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'nisarg_new_excerpt_more' );

function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 80;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );

/**
 * Return the post URL.
 *
 * @uses get_url_in_content() to get the URL in the post meta (if it exists) or
 * the first link found in the post content.
 *
 * Falls back to the post permalink if no URL is found in the post.
 *
 *  * @return string The Link format URL.
 */
function nisarg_get_link_url() {
    $nisarg_content = get_the_content();
    $nisarg_has_url = get_url_in_content( $nisarg_content );

    return ( $nisarg_has_url ) ? $nisarg_has_url : apply_filters( 'the_permalink', get_permalink() );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a new menu here:

```
function register_nisarg_menus() {
        // This theme uses wp_nav_menu() in one location.
        register_nav_menus( array(
            'primary' => esc_html__( 'Top Primary Menu', 'nisarg' ),
            'my_new_menu' => esc_html__( 'My New Menu', 'nisarg' ) //this is the new line
        ) );
    }
```

and you use it like this in your HTML code to output the menu, using the ID:

```
<?php
    wp_nav_menu(array(
       'theme_location' => 'my_new_menu'
    ));
?>
```

you can read more about the menus [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/navigation-menus/).